# Facebook page list without login/access token

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i am using Fabook api to get facebook page list by using search query   `GET graph.facebook.com/search?q={your-query}&type={object-type}`

but i have to login and get access token and userid  before using this search api query ,

is there any other way to get facebook page list without login/ access token  to get list of facebook pages

Comment: The documentation clearly states that you need a user access token to perform a search.